# OpenGL glBegin and glPushMatrix

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I try to design a scene with 3 spheres and one line horizontal as equator. I got to draw the 3 spheres but I don't know why the line is not draw.

This is my code, for if you can see where I'm wrong:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void render(void);

void reshape(int w, int h);

int angle = 90;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
  glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);
  glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
  glutCreateWindow("Planets");

  glutDisplayFunc(render);
  glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}


void render(void) {
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

  // Equator
  glBegin(GL_LINES);
  glColor3f(1,1,1);
  glLineWidth(1);
  glTranslated(0, 0, 0);
  glVertex2f(0, 2);
  glVertex2f(2,2);
  glEnd();

  // Sun
  glPushMatrix();
  glLoadIdentity();
  glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  glTranslated(0, 0, -2);
  glRotated(angle, 1, 0, 0);
  glutWireSphere(.3, 20, 20);
  glPopMatrix();

  //Earth
  glPushMatrix();
  glLoadIdentity();
  glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  glTranslated(0.7, 0, -2);
  glRotated(angle, 1, 0, 0);
  glutWireSphere(.15, 20, 20);
  glPopMatrix();

  // Moon
  glPushMatrix();
  glLoadIdentity();
  glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  glTranslated(1, 0, -2);
  glRotated(angle, 1, 0, 0);
  glutWireSphere(.05, 10, 10);
  glPopMatrix();

  glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w, int h) {
  const double ar = (double) w / (double) h;
  glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glFrustum(-ar, ar, -1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 100.0);

  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();
}
```

Comment: Where do you tell it to draw a line? You specified two vertices. And how much of a line will you get between `(0, 2)` and `(2, 2)`?

Comment: matrix modification command calls (like glTranslate is) are not allowed between glBegin / glEnd. That being said you should not use glBegin / glEnd in the first place. It's been outdated for almost 20 years now.

Comment: @WeatherVane: glBegin(GL_LINES) starts drawing lines, every pair of glVertex calls makes a line. and (0,2) → (2,2) could be any length and direction depending on the transformation matrices set. In the case of OPs projection matrix the vertices lie outside of the projection volume though.

Comment: @datenwolf thank you, I made an Orrery too with OpenGL, but didn't draw lines!

Comment: Note: glTranslatef isn't allowed inside glBegin/glEnd, IIRC (It will set an error flag and do nothing). Neither is glLineWidth. In fact most functions aren't, apart from the ones that set vertex attributes (like the texcoords, normals, vertex positions, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify a frustum that has the near clip plane at z=-2. Your intended line would be drawn at z=0, thus outside the projection volume, thereby clipped into non-rendering.

glTranslate(0,0,0) is a no-op BTW.

Comment: @immibis: No, it's actually -2 (negative 2). The default coordinate system for OpenGL with these functions is +X → right, +Y → up, +Z → out of the screen. However the view looks "into" the screen, thus the near and far plane specified with glFrustum (or gluPerspective) are in the -Z direction.

Comment: @datenwolf Thanks a lot. I don't get understand completely how work it but your comment was a great help to me.